# PHP Issue - function output is 000

Tags: php, yahoo-messenger

I've been trying to make a CLI application that logs Yahoo! messenger login dates/times for certain users using a third party, but this isn't really getting anywhere. Even though checking iself works when used individually, it does not seem to when using the while & foreach too. checkAvailability outputs "000". Could anyone please fix this and perhaps optimize it?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$users[0] = "|59|62|157|85|218|78|135|43|63|145|151|173|157|93|107|90|84|129|140|110|55|28|210|212|80|128|252|127|15|192|223|154|177|39|129|191|62|17|113|236|2|168&t=0.23704720849047";
$users[1] = "|70|255|229|124|194|244|242|223|73|250|184|237|222|251|8|243|104|4|70|125|205|177|229|255|178|244|123|251|13|157|220|47|88|247|15|0&t=0.04614829820959876";

function checkAvailability($user){
    $dataGot = file_get_contents("http://www.imvisible.ro/getstatus.php?id=".$user);
    $fullText = explode("|", $dataGot);
    $status_coded = $fullText[0];
    echo $status_coded;
    return $status_coded;
}


while(true) {
    foreach($users as $user) {
        $user['oldstatus'] = $user['status'];

        if (checkAvailability($user) == "1" and $user['oldstatus'] != "online") {
            $user['status'] = "online";
            echo "online";
        } elseif (checkAvailability($user) == "3" and $user['oldstatus'] != "invisible") {
            $user['status'] = "invisible";
            echo "invisible";
        } elseif (checkAvailability($user) == "2" and $user['oldstatus'] != "offline") {
            $user['status'] = "offline";
            echo "offline";
        } else {
            $user['status'] = "error";
            echo "error";
        }
        if ($user['status'] != $user['oldstatus']) {
            echo $user." a fost detectat ca ".$user['status']." la ".date(DATE_RFC822).".\n";
        }
    }
    sleep(60);
    sleep(60);
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps indent your code?

Comment: Contact http://www.imvisible.ro/ and ask them for support. We can't guess how this file is meant to be used, and what it should return.

Comment: what is a normal ID for a user?

Comment: What does a sample `var_dump($fullText)` look like? Can you add it to your question.  A lot of the code you are showing is probably unnecessary to show if the problem lies within the `checkAvailability` function.

Comment: Don't call `checkAvailability()` multiple times. Just call it once and store its value in a variable.

Comment: From http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php - 

> On failure, **file_get_contents()** will return **FALSE**.

`checkAvailability()` is called three times and fails three times. You're not echoing 0, you're echoing `(bool)false`.

Try `var_dump($dataGot)` to see the result of that call.

Comment: @LeahL. Even though that is very good thinking, when going to the URL you will see that it also outputs `0`. e.g. http://www.imvisible.ro/getstatus.php?id=1. Also echoing `false` doesn't output anything.

Comment: http://codepad.org/XxiA7lLv

Comment: @Mike Except he's outputting to the CLI directly, (obviously) without buffering, etc.  Also, navigating to the URL he's trying to acquire through file_get_contents via a browser only demonstrates that the content exists, not that he's necessarily got the fopen wrappers set to allow him to load it, and speculating on what his error suppression might be set to is also not terribly useful...

Comment: @LeahL. When I edited the above post it unhid the first 3 lines of code. There's your error suppression answer. And echoing a variable set to `false` doesn't output anything even by to the CLI.

Comment: @Mike Yeah, I see that now :) **To clarify: I'm not saying it does that, but that it's totally possible to trigger output on false (ie, function shutdown, overloading magic, etc.), and that I've seen it before.** I know it might appear obvious, but I won't just assume 0 is a string just because it **should** be, because I'm not assuming that `echo` is what is *actually outputting* here. So, I'd rather just ask to see the var_dump (showing variable type, removing all doubt) than waste cycles based on presumptions re: what we're shown here (echo) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An endless runing CLI application in PHP in not the best solution. Its better when you make a cronjob and run the script every one or every to minutes. Then you can store the status or what you need in a  database or a file.

I have looked at your scripted and test the script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$users[0] = "|59|62|157|85|218|78|135|43|63|145|151|173|157|93|107|90|84|129|140|110|55|28|210|212|80|128|252|127|15|192|223|154|177|39|129|191|62|17|113|236|2|168&t=0.23704720849047";
$users[1] = "|70|255|229|124|194|244|242|223|73|250|184|237|222|251|8|243|104|4|70|125|205|177|229|255|178|244|123|251|13|157|220|47|88|247|15|0&t=0.04614829820959876";

function checkAvailability($user){
    $dataGot = file_get_contents("http://www.imvisible.ro/getstatus.php?id=".$user);
    $fullText = explode("|", $dataGot);
    $status_coded = $fullText[0];
    return $status_coded;
}

while(true) {
    foreach($users as $key => $user) {
        $userStatus[$key] = checkAvailability($user);     

        if(!isset($userStatusRet[$key]['oldstatus'])) {
            $userStatusRet[$key]['oldstatus'] = '';
        }

        if(!isset($userStatusRet[$key]['status'])) {
            $userStatusRet[$key]['status'] = '';
        }

        $userStatusRet[$key]['oldstatus'] = $userStatusRet[$key]['status'];

        if ($userStatus[$key] == "1" and $userStatusRet[$key]['oldstatus'] != "online") {
            $userStatusRet['status'] = "online";
            echo "User ".$key.": online\n";
        } elseif ($userStatus[$key] == "3" and $userStatusRet[$key]['oldstatus'] != "invisible") {
            $userStats['status'] = "invisible";
           echo "User ".$key.": invisible\n";
        } elseif ($userStatus[$key] == "2" and $userStatusRet[$key]['oldstatus'] != "offline") {
            $userStatusRet[$key]['status'] = "offline";
            echo "User ".$key.": offline\n";
        } else {
            $userStatusRet[$key]['status'] = "error";
            echo "User ".$key.": error\n";
        }
    }
    sleep(5);
}
```

Its not the best solution but the problem in your case is, that you can't write in the `$user` output. I have made here a new variable with the user id as iterator. When you run the script you can see the output:

```
User 0: online
User 1: offline
User 0: online
User 1: error
User 0: online
User 1: offline
```

Comment: The output from codepad is not correct ;) I run this on my mashine with PHP 5.4 and its working well. 

Disallowed system call: SYS_nanosleep

And you should read the output from codepad. The syscall to sleep or anything else is not allowed.